# How to set the focus on a child element with Modern UI

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, textbox, focus

I got a LoginPage.xaml here:

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="NeoClinic.MAS.LoginPage"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                  xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
                  Title="Login" IsTitleVisible="True"                         
                  ContentSource="Pages\LoginBasic.xaml"
                  WindowState="Maximized"
                  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
                  Closing="LoginPage_OnClosing"
                  >

    <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
        <mui:LinkGroup x:Name="LoginLinkGroup" DisplayName="Login" >
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>

                <mui:Link x:Name="LoginLink" DisplayName="Login" Source="Pages\LoginBasic.xaml" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>

    </mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>

</mui:ModernWindow>
```

and a UserControl here:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NeoClinic.MAS.Pages.LoginBasic"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
                 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
                 xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
                 x:Name="BasicLogin"
                 mc:Ignorable="d" 
                 Height="550"
                 Width="1280">
        <Grid Style="{StaticResource ContentRoot}" >
            <Grid ShowGridLines="False" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />

                </Grid.RowDefinitions>



                <Grid x:Name="GridBanner" ShowGridLines="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                    <Button x:Name="ImageButton" Content="Image"  Grid.Column="0" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

                    <Label Content="MIDAS SYSTEM" FontStretch="ExtraExpanded" FontSize="70" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="10" 
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

                </Grid>

                <Border x:Name="GroupBoxLogin"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="10">
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Content="User Name" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5"/>
                        <Label Content="Password" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5"/>
                        <Label x:Name="NotificationLabel" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="23" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5"/>

                        <TextBox x:Name="UserNameTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="23" Margin="5,5,5,0"  PreviewKeyUp="UserNameTextBox_OnPreviewKeyUp"/>

                        <TextBox x:Name="PasswordTextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"  FontWeight="Normal" FontSize="23" Margin="5,5,5,0" PreviewKeyUp="PasswordTextBox_OnPreviewKeyUp"/>


                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Background="{x:Null}">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                            <mui:ModernButton x:Name="OkButton" Content="Ok" Grid.Column="4"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Click="OkButton_OnClick"/>
                            <mui:ModernButton x:Name="ExitButton" Content="Exit" Grid.Column="6" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black" Click="ExitButton_OnClick"/>

                        </Grid>


                    </Grid>
                </Border>


            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

I tried every thing I researched in Google about auto focusing a control such as textbox but the insertion point only appears without blinking, and when I press a key, it doesn't appear to the textbox unless I click the textbox and start pressing keys again

here is my contructor code for the Login Page:

```
public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and here is my contructor in the UserControl:

```
    public LoginBasic()
{
    InitializeComponent();       
    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, UserNameTextBox);// the insertion appears but not active it seems
}
```

Comment: where is `txtName`? do you mean `UserNameTextBox`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it

```
public LoginBasic()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(this, UserNameTextBox);
            //Keyboard.Focus(UserNameTextBox);

            this.IsVisibleChanged += LoginControl_IsVisibleChanged; 


        }




void LoginControl_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
            new Action(() => UserNameTextBox.Focus()));
        }
    }
```

source is based on
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/478376/Setting-focus-to-a-control-inside-a-usercontrol-in)